# Setting up a cron job corectly within wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, cron

I am having difficulty doing this and have checked over previous questions however they do not seem to be working.

So far i have disabled the default wordpress cron by adding below to my wp-config.php:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Then i have attempted to schedule my task to run every 5 mins from within my plugins main php file:

```
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["5min"])){
        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 5*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["30min"])){
        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 30*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes'));
    }
    return $schedules;
}

add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

function schedule_my_cron(){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '5min', 'fivemin_schedule_hook');
}

if(!wp_get_schedule('fivemin_schedule_hook')){
    add_action('init', 'schedule_my_cron',10);
}

function fivemin_schedule_hook() {
    get_feed();
}
```

So the above appears to be scheduling my event within database however have 100's of entries when checking cron schedule with:

```
<?php print_r(get_option('cron')); ?>
```

I have also made sure to update my crontab with below:

```
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://wordpress.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

However my task does not appear to be running and am concerned about the amount of entries within database for this 5min job.

Each entry looks like below:

```
 Array ( [1524308364] => Array ( [fivemin_schedule_hook] => Array ( [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array ( [schedule] => 5min [args] => Array ( ) [interval] => 300 ) ) )
```

I have tried debugging wp-cron.php by echoing out the $hook when it tries to fire and my hook is shown when i visit wp-cron.php directly. The actual function however just does not seem to fire.

Comment: Have you checked that calling to `http://wordpress.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` by hand works?

Comment: Yeah checked that doesn't seem to fire my function

Comment: Your crontab can be scheluded every 5 minutes with `*/5 * * * ` https://crontab.guru/#*/5_*_*_*_*

Comment: Yeah i figured it be fine as long as it was more often than 5 min as may do a cron for every min as well

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Replace this:

```
function schedule_my_cron(){
    wp_schedule_event(time(), '5min', 'fivemin_schedule_hook');
}

if(!wp_get_schedule('fivemin_schedule_hook')){
    add_action('init', 'schedule_my_cron',10);
}
```

..with this:

```
function schedule_my_cron(){
    // Schedules the event if it's NOT already scheduled.
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_5min_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'my_5min_event' );
    }
}

// Registers and schedules the my_5min_event cron event.
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_my_cron' );

// Runs fivemin_schedule_hook() function every 5 minutes.
add_action( 'my_5min_event', 'fivemin_schedule_hook' );
//add_action( 'my_5min_event', 'another_function_to_call' );
//add_action( 'my_5min_event', 'another_function_to_call2' );
```

But a more appropriate/preferred way is to add this in the activation function for your plugin:

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'my_5min_event' );
```

Example:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation' );
function my_plugin_activation() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_5min_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'my_5min_event' );
    }
}
```

..which would be used in place of the following:

```
function schedule_my_cron(){
    // Schedules the event if it's NOT already scheduled.
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_5min_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), '5min', 'my_5min_event' );
    }
}

// Registers and schedules the my_5min_event cron event.
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_my_cron' );
```

And *add this somewhere in the deactivation function for your plugin*:

```
wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_5min_event' );
```

Example:

```
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_deactivation' );
function my_plugin_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'my_5min_event' );
}
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#Examples for more details.

Comment: I will have a go at this i think i got it working although feel it is running every min at the moment. Thanks for your help am a bit new to wordpress and just trying to get my bearings.

Comment: Hopefully the code works for you, because I've actually tested it and it created just one event and that it triggered the function `fivemin_schedule_hook()` hooked to the event on a 5 minutes interval.